# What's a convenient environment for edit-run-repeat with short Clojure programs?

Tags: clojure, ide, editor

I've been hacking away at the 4clojure.com problem set and having a lot of fun. I've done a few dozen of the Elementary and Easy level problems.

However, my "development" environment for this work leaves something to be desired. Basically, I'm writing one-liners, either in the Leiningen REPL or Sublime Text's "SublimeREPL" for Clojure.

I'd like to be able to unpack those one-liners as I work (few solutions need to be longer than a few lines that I've seen so far, but one line is pretty condensed at least for my newbie eyes).

My desired workflow is, as I implied in the title, is to have a single file for each solution, and to be able to iteratively hack on it, save it, run it and see the output.

I'm on OS X and Ubuntu; my primary editor is Sublime Text, but I do use Emacs as well. CIDER perhaps?

Comment: I'd suggest starting with Emacs Live or Emacs Prelude, both of which already integrate CIDER and a great deal of other functionality besides.

Comment: Light Table might also be worth poking at, at least while you're still working on smaller code segments rather than large programs.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I did try Emacs Live (but couldn't remember the name so I didn't mention it above). I liked the promise, but my first reaction was that it had turned my fairly staid Emacs setup into an urecognizable, if friendly, behemoth. I'll check out Emacs Prelude.

Comment: I'm using [NightCode](https://nightcode.info/) as a gateway to Leiningen and Emacs.

Comment: ... except that Nightcode doesn't use Emacs :(.

Comment: After trying Emacs Live again, I remembered the main reason I ditched it -- it replaced my emacs config wholesale, removing certain packages that I need for work.  These seem like good solutions if you either 1) don't use emacs for anything else or 2) have the time/patience/skillz to integrate your needed packages back into the Live/Prelude config.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs with, as Charles suggests, either the [Emacs Live](https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live) config or Emacs Prelude (or [mine](https://github.com/thearthur/arthur-s-emacs-config)).
Open a file, hack away, and run

- <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd><kbd>Alt-j</kbd> to start up a clojure repl through Cider (nrepl's replacement)
- <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd> to load the file
- <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd><kbd>Alt-n</kbd> to put the repl in that namespace,
- and hack away.

And if you're installing Emacs Live you might as well play with Overtone and make some "music"